# no visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'setTitle'

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

ok so im just starting out with objective c and iv got a very random error im not sure what its trying to point out to me
I have this on xviewContoller.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *helloButton;
```

on the xviewController.m along with

```
- (IBAction)showAlrt:(id)sender;
```

with this in the method at the bottom of this page

```
- (IBAction)showAlrt:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"xxxx"
                          message:@"xxxx"

                          delegate:nil

                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
                          [alert show];

                        [self.helloButton setTitle:@"click"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I am then getting this error

no visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'setTitle'

on like [self.helloButton setTitle.....

can someone help please.

Comment: i think its something wrong with my @property setting but im unsure what to change it too :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[self.helloButton setTitle:@"click"]
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

change to

```
[self.helloButton setTitle:@"click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: my god it was just a ] that causing me the problem :( thanks tho :)

Comment: im so used to c# and c++ that is is quite different so thanks

Comment: is there a reference guide for error codes ? i have another now that says thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: No, there is no error codes but error messages, which would tell you something wrong.

Comment: I think its because I had a text input bot on my storyboard and it wasn't linked to anything